# How make ruby write my JSON correctly?

Tags: ruby, json, format

How can I make Ruby write the way my JSON is structured?

I want this way:

```
{
  "keywords": [
    {
      "id": "1" ,
      "product": "car"
    } ,
    {
      "id": "2" ,
      "product": "mobile"
    }
  ]
}
```

When i run the code with a 3rd object,
Ruby writes:

```
{
  "keywords": [
    {
      "id": "1" ,
      "product": "car"
    } ,
    {
      "id": "2" ,
      "product": "mobile"
    }
  ],"3":"ball"
}
```

I'm generating the JSON this way:

```
data_hash.store(3, 'ball')
json_output = data_hash.to_json

file = File.open('keywords.json','w')
file.write(json_output)
```

Comment: Maybe you show us `3rd object`. ? And how you generate JSON?

Comment: the ruby is writing outside the keyword level and without the keys. How can I code a pattern(?) for that?

Comment: Do you read the documentation for a [`store`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-store) method? And it's not clear for me, desired output. All works fine here. What is your question?

Comment: No, didn't read. I'd like the "3":"ball" inside the keywords level

Comment: That's how programmer works for now, ask question on SO. no need RTFM. So bad, so sad

Comment: Sorry, I pressed [enter] after "No, didn't read."After that I completed what I was supposed to talk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want use the following instead of `store`:

```
data_hash['keywords'] << { 'id' => '3', 'product' => 'ball' }
```